# How to append the results HTML output file on JMeter tests using Ant

Tags: html, testing, ant, jmeter, output

I have the following issue.

I have 100+ Jmeter tests as separate files with the tendency to add more. Using Ant I have configured the results to come into a separate output HTML file for each test. So now when I have 100+ tests I get 100+ resulting HTML files. And I need to check every single one if the tests run OK.

My question is how to make the Ant append the results into one HTML file for all 100+ tests so I can view with a single glance that the tests run OK.

I guess I either need to modify the ..extras/build.xml file in Jmeter or modify the command line where I invoke my tests via Ant.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [JMeter Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/) try this - it uses a `FileSet` for the testplans:

```
<jmeter
    jmeterhome="c:\jakarta-jmeter-1.8.1"
    resultlog="${basedir}/loadtests/JMeterResults.jtl">
    <testplans dir="${basedir}/loadtests" includes="*.jmx"/>
</jmeter>
```

So, it will only be one result file generated and then transformed into HTML.